# Kotlin unable to stop handler running

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-handler

I am running a handler that updates a textView element. The handler is started and stopped at the click of a button but once I start it, I cannot stop it.

```
fun updateTextView(handler: Handler, run: Boolean = true) {
    val runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            // update text view element
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
        }
    }
    if (run) handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500)
    // this should stop it?
    else handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
}
```

And my function to detect clicks

```
val textHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

private fun setupClickListeners() {
    startLive.setOnClickListener{
        updateTextView(textHandler)
    }

    stopLive.setOnClickListener{
        updateTextView(textHandler, run = false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `val runnable` declaration and instantiation out of the `updateTextView()` function. As is it now, you're creating a new instance each time `updateTextView()` runs, so `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` isn't going to do anything because that new instance was never posted.

Comment: So i declared it at the top of my class with: private lateinit var runnable: Runnable. And changed the line in the method to runnable = Runnable { and now the handler doesnt run at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you, but it sounds like that's still instantiating a new `Runnable` each time.

Comment: Maybe, im new to Kotlin and can't quite grasp it. So should I remove the runnable completely from the updateTextView method and instead make a runnable on button click? So something like runnable = Runnable { updateTextView } in the setonclicklistener method?

Comment: Can't you just instantiate it on the declaration line? It never needs to change, does it?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't change but I looked at lots of examples and I can't figure out how to instantiate it, because its not as simple as it is in Java...Regardless I managed to get it working with my earlier-mentioned approach of putting it in the setOnClickListener method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It works exactly the same as Java, it's just the syntax is a little different. If you want to be able to cancel the Runnable (since it reposts itself) you need to keep a reference to that Runnable, or a token that's used to ID the Runnable when it posts. If you just keep a single instance of the Runnable as a top-level variable, you can easily post it to start it and pass it to `removeCallbacks` to stop it. The method you posted just creates a *new* Runnable, posts it, then immediately removes it again. And if you didn't remove it, with no stored reference you wouldn't be able to stop it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general way to do what you need:

```
// store an instance of your runnable task
val runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        // update text view element
        handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
    }
}

fun startRunnable() {
    // you could just run it to get it going, since it posts itself
    runnable.run()
}

fun stopRunnable() {
    // remove this specific instance from the message queue
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
}
```

Like I said in the comment, your version is creating a *new* `Runnable` instance every time you run the function - then after posting it to the queue, it immediately removes it again. If you didn't remove it, it would run - but you wouldn't be able to stop it, because you don't have a stored reference to the instance you created, so you can't pass it to `removeCallbacks`. (Running the function again like you're doing just creates a *new* `Runnable`, so cancelling that won't affect the other one.)

By storing the `Runnable` as a variable, you have access to it - so you can easily pass it to `removeCallbacks`, and reuse it by posting it again. This doesn't work if you actually *need* multiple instances (like you have separate tasks going on) - in that case, you'd need to store references to each `Runnable` you create, and have some way to coordinate which one you're cancelling